# Configuration doesn't work for using vundle on vim

Tags: vim, vundle

I install Vundle by the step of its github [homepage](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows). I have installed the git, curl and clone the vundle to my directory.

While I encountered problems as follows:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc:
line   21:
E518: Unknown option: $VIM/vimfiles/bundle/vundle/
line   22:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line   23:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
line   24:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'bling/vim-airline'
```

Here is a snippet of my _vimrc(in windows):

```
filetype off
set rtp += $VIM/vimfiles/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc('$VIM/vimfiles/bundle/')
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'bling/vim-airline'
filetype plugin indent on     " required!
"vundle
```

Comment: Try `set rtp+= $VIM/vimfiles/bundle/vundle/` without the space between `rtp` and `+=`.

Comment: It still does not work.

Comment: Haha, stupid me, I removed one space but not the other!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be **no spaces in the `:set` command**:

```
set rtp+=$VIM/vimfiles/bundle/vundle/
```

That caused the `E518: Unknown option`.

Furthermore, I would not recommended to put your personal customizations under `C:\Program Files\vim`; in newer Windows versions, this may only be writable with admin rights. Rather, take the `_vimrc` from there as a template, and copy all of your customizations to `$HOME`.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to get the suggested line that had a tilde (~) instead of $VIM working. Thanks! I wish they would update the articles and install instructions. I'll try to do a pull request.